# Is Using a List instead of an Array for generating Prime Numbers more efficient?

Tags: java, list, primes, sieve-of-eratosthenes

Based on one of the examples,below is a prime number generator for a given cutoff.

My question is in some implementations ,an array is used to mark all the numbers which are multiples until only primes are left.The below is similar in that way but in the below example we need not maintain all the numbers in the array and check if the elements below it are crossed or not during the prime test and only which are not crossed are used in the division.

So is the below better where in we just maintain the primes in a list and which reduces the number of comparisons ?

```
class PrimesBySieve
{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        generateTo(20);
    }

    public static void generateTo(int cutoff) 
    {
        try {
            ArrayList<Integer> primes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            primes.add(2);


            int j;
            boolean isPrime;
            for(int i=3;i<=cutoff;i++){

                //Check if i is Prime by dividing with all the primes in the list which       
                //are smaller than i
                //Any number can be expressed as a product of primes
                j=0;
                isPrime=true;
                while(primes.get(j)*primes.get(j)<=i && j<=primes.size()){
                    if(i%primes.get(j)==0){
                        isPrime=false;
                    }
                    j++;
                }

                //Add the prime to the output.
                if(isPrime){
                    primes.add(i);
                }
            }   
            System.out.println(primes);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: see this http://www.javafaq.nu/java-article1111.html

Comment: how does that relate to efficiency.Even an ArrayList internally has an array and assume that I have initialized it with a required capacity.

Comment: Your question was also about usage of list vs array, the above article has some points about it. But basically your whole algorithm is not as efficient as it should be as you can see from @peter.petrov answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your algorithm is not efficient. So regardless of which data structure you use
you won't get a great performance speed-up. You should use another algorithm
called 'Sieve of Eratosthenes'. Try to implement this algorithm and you'll notice
the difference in performance (especially for bigger values of N). Currently you
have N=20.

[Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes)

Comment: From sieve of eratosthenes, we would be crossing of all the multiples of say a certain number x;And we do this for x=2 to n.Is the efficiency because we are not dividing all the prime numbers below the number x with x to find if it is prime ?

Comment: @whokares For a given N, your algorithm is doing more operations than the sieve algorithm. So using list or array - that is not the main question/problem here.